# Computational text recommendation for non-linear dynamics/differential equations? (flows, maps, nonlinear time-series analysis)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, soft-question, dynamical-systems

I'm starting a free online course through Santa Fe University in Nonlinear Dynamics. I've taken a lot of upper elective undergraduate mathematics/physics but I'm looking for a text that specifically covers flows, maps and nonlinear time-series analysis with a more computational possibly numeral approximation approach. I don't really know where to start with supplemental texts and I want all that I can get my hands on.

Everyone seems to recommend Strogatz. I'm familiar with his work, I've already watched all his lectures on Chaos on youtube but I'm not familiar with his work enough to know if his book specifically covers these three areas that I will be covering in that course.

https://www.complexityexplorer.org/courses/60-nonlinear-dynamics-mathematical-and-computational-approaches-fall-2016

The course doesn't recommend any texts, and I've found their videos needing supplement in the past. Any ideas?

Comment: [Solving ODEs II; Stiff and differential algebraic problems](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540604525) by Hairer and Wanner is a really good numerical book. It has a couple of sections dedicated to GSPT style problems which can be useful. Though this book is quite dense, and depends on a background knowledge of numerics, so you may need to read book I first.

Comment: I've taken a numerical methods class in MATLAB. I'll look at both and see where I stand, thank you.