# Nonlinear dynamics book for self study

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, book-recommendation, nonlinear-dynamics

I have to learn basic nonlinear dynamics on my own for a project, and I'm trying to find a text that could serve the purpose. I'm in search of something not that cryptical, maybe easy to read, but at the same time precise and exhaustive: I found the Strogatz book too dispersive for instance... 
Anyone could help me?
Thanks!

Comment: DIFFERENTIAL EQUATIONS, DYNAMICAL SYSTEMS, AND AN INTRODUCTION
TO CHAOS, Morris W. Hirsch,Stephen Smale,Robert L. Devaney also you can try DIFFERENTIAL EQUATIONS,Paul Blanchard, R.L. Devaney

Comment: Related, in Physics SE: [Self-study book for dynamical systems theory?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/353841/75633).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Above are nice texts but I would also like to add a few texts and links which may help -

For motivation and literature of how Chaos theory came into existence - refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos:_Making_a_New_Science

The text by Steven Strogatz is also nice!, better to also see his lectures on Youtube if you want for the basics :) here

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ycJEoqmQvwg&list=PLbN57C5Zdl6j_qJA-pARJnKsmROzPnO9V.

Also this question has some similarity as in the project you will definitely want to mention graphs and curves  - [Computational text recommendation for non-linear dynamics/differential equations? (flows, maps, nonlinear time-series analysis)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1916280/computational-text-recommendation-for-non-linear-dynamics-differential-equations?rq=1)

and

[Reference request: Nonlinear dynamics graduate reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/709463/reference-request-nonlinear-dynamics-graduate-reference?rq=1)

may help too!.

Finally, there is a chat room created by me dedicated to Dynamical Systems and Chaos theory-

https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55403/dynamical-systems-and-chaos-theory

where you may ask queries about it and I would be happy to help, I am also starting in it :'( . But I would admit that the room is not so active though, I hope it may be active later in future :).

All the best with your project!!

Answer (score 2):

In no particular order

1. [Nonlinear Waves, Solitons and Chaos](http://www.cambridge.org/gb/academic/subjects/physics/nonlinear-science-and-fluid-dynamics/nonlinear-waves-solitons-and-chaos-2nd-edition?format=PB#xi5X5GXrRr5PFCDR.97) A solid, entry level text that is fully updated now to include Plasma Phycs applications.
2. [Solitons, An Introduction](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Solitons-Introduction-Cambridge-Applied-Mathematics/dp/0521336554) Drazin and Johnson offers this classic text in the subject area of Solitons, which although confined to Solitons and thier solutions (Backlund Transformations and hirota's method) the first few chapters are classically based in entry level Nonlinear PDEs.
3. [Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Nonlinear-Dynamics-Chaos-Applications-Nonlinearity/dp/0738204536) This is a great place to start as an undergraduate text.
4. [Nonlinear Oscillations, Dynamical Systems, and Bifurcations of Vector Fields](https://www.springer.com/gb/book/9780387908199) This is another classic in the field, pricey but definitely worth it as a 'go-to' textbook.
5. [Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems](http://paguirre.mat.utfsm.cl/edo-2015-2/perko.pdf) This textbook's pitch is in between list items $3$ and $4$, and offeres an intermediate level text.